# Height of flex items not remaining fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page with three rows from top to bottom, fix height header(100px) at the top and fix height footer(100px) at the bottom, the middle take up the rest height.

[image]

demo is here: http://jiazhengblog.com/test/flex-study.html

The result is what I expected.

But after I add some contents into the middle row, I found that if contents height is higher than its parents it will make parent height higher than expected. That is the middle area height is a little bit higher and both header and footer height are shortened(less than 100px). When I resize the browser window all rows height are changed.

[image]

How can I make the header and footer height fixed in this case?

demo is here: http://jiazhengblog.com/test/flex-study-2.html

Comment: I found a solution: add min-height to header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). That means that flex items can shrink from their initial size in order to remain inside the container (i.e., they cannot overflow).

That's what is happening in your code. The header and footer are shrinking to accommodate the height of the content in the middle item.

You need to disable `flex-shrink`.

Instead of this:

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    background: pink;
}

#footer {
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Try this:

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: pink;
}

#footer {
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0; /* not really necessary; default is 0 */
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Or even better (in terms of efficiency), this:

```
#header {
    flex: 0 0 100px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
    background: pink;
}

#footer {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using min-height in header and footer like this:

```
#header {
    background: pink;
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#footer {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```